# Appending a string to a string array while validating the string. c++

Tags: c++, arrays, string, append

The problem I'm having is prompting the user to enter whatever item appears on the console window and I have to then check if that string is valid. If it's valid, I have to then append that string, display all the items that appear in the player's inventory and deduct the player's money accordingly.

The problem starts at the playerInput function.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cctype>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

const int items = 5;
const string ShopInventory[items] = {"Helms", "Boots", "Swords", "Axes", "Leather Armors"};
const int ItemPrices[items]= {10, 5, 20, 30, 50};

void PrintShop();
int PlayerInput(string [], int&);

int main()
{
   string PlayerInventory[items];
   int playerMoney = 100;
   char Response;

   cout << "\t\tWelcome traveler to my lovely shop. \n";

   cout << "\nFeel free to browse many of the wonderful items within";
   cout << " this store. " << endl;

   PrintShop();

   while(toupper(Response) != 'N')
   {
      cout << PlayerInput(PlayerInventory, playerMoney);

      cout << "\nIs there anything else that you would like to buy? ";
      cout << "Enter n or N to quit.\nElse enter y or Y to continue. ";
      cin >> Response;

      while(toupper(Response) != 'Y' && toupper(Response) != 'N')
      {
         cerr << "\nSorry, wrong input. Please try again.  ";
         cin >> Response;
      }
   }

   return 0;
}

void PrintShop()
{
   cout << endl;

   cout << "     ***** Shop Inventory ***** " << endl << endl;

   cout << "Shop items " << "\t\tPrice Per Item. " << endl << endl;

   for(int i=0; i<items; i++)
   {
      cout << i+1 << ".) " << left << setw(22) << ShopInventory[i];
      cout << left << setw(3) << ItemPrices[i] << " Gold" << endl;
   }
}

int PlayerInput(string PlayerInventory[], int &playerMoney)
{
   string input;

   cout << "\nEnter what you would like to buy. ";
   getline(cin, input);

   while(find(begin(ShopInventory), end(ShopInventory), input) == end(ShopInventory))
   {
      cout << "\nThe item that you enter isn't in my inventory. ";
      getline(cin, input);
   }

   return playerMoney;
}
```

Comment: You say there is a problem but you only provide code without an indication of what the problem is.

Comment: My problem is that while validating if the string the user inputs appears in the shopinventory array, I have to then append that string to the playerinventory array and I don't know how without adding all the items from the shopinventory array into the playerinventory array.

Comment: Then I have to tell the player that he has x amount of axes, helms, armor, etc. Then I have to deduct x amount from his wallet.

Comment: Well there's no problems with the program itself. I've just hit a brick wall when it comes to trying to append a string to a string array. Every thing I've mention in the description is a problem that'll have to face in this program. Once I append the string that I validated into the playerInventory array, then I can move  on to the other problems in this program(Even validating the string was tough to do).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is problem with the way you read the `y/Y/n/N` response.

After the line

```
  cin >> Response;
```

is executed, the newline character is still left on the input stream.

Change that to:

```
  cin >> Response;
  cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
```

to take care of that. You need to do that in couple of places.

About appending the input to the player's inventory. You can use the following:

```
int PlayerInput(string PlayerInventory[], int& playerMoney)
{
   string input;

   while (true)
   {
      cout << "\nEnter what you would like to buy. ";
      getline(cin, input);

      auto it = find(begin(ShopInventory), end(ShopInventory), input);
      if ( it == end(ShopInventory))
      {
         cout << "\nThe item that you enter isn't in my inventory. ";
         continue;
      }

      int index = std::distance(begin(ShopInventory), it);

      // Use the knowledge that the default constructor of std::strings
      // constructs an empty string.
      if (!PlayerInventory[index].empty() )
      {
         cout << "\nThe item that you enter is already in your inventory. ";
         continue;
      }
      else
      {
         // Add the item to the player's inventory.
         PlayerInventory[index] = input;

         // Subtract the item's price from the player's available money
         playerMoney -= ItemPrices[index];

         break;
      }
   } 

   return playerMoney;
}
```

A better alternative will be to use a `std::set<std::string>` to represent the player's inventory. In that case, your function will be:

```
int PlayerInput(set<string>& PlayerInventory, int& playerMoney)
{
   string input;

   while (true)
   {
      cout << "\nEnter what you would like to buy. ";
      getline(cin, input);

      auto it = find(begin(ShopInventory), end(ShopInventory), input);
      if ( it == end(ShopInventory))
      {
         cout << "\nThe item that you enter isn't in my inventory. ";
         continue;
      }

      int index = std::distance(begin(ShopInventory), it);

      if (PlayerInventory.find(input) != PlayerInventory.end())
      {
         cout << "\nThe item that you enter is already in your inventory. ";
         continue;
      }
      else
      {
         // Add the item to the player's inventory.
         PlayerInventory.insert(input);

         // Subtract the item's price from the player's available money
         playerMoney -= ItemPrices[index];

         break;
      }
   } 

   return playerMoney;
}
```

Comment: My program didn't eat up any of my input buffer(as far as I know)r. My problem is trying to append a string(input) to a string array(the playerInventory array). That is where I stump.

Comment: Great explanation. You explained everything perfectly

Comment: The only thing I want to know is why did you use auto? I have never used auto before and I don't know when I would use it.

Comment: @ChronoTrigger, use `auto` when the type is too complex to type, or not easily deducible given the template parameters. For a brief introduction, see http://www.stroustrup.com/C++11FAQ.html#auto.